# R: How to subset a dataframe based on a regression model (glmm)

Tags: r, regression, subset, mixed-models

I have a large data set (~60k rows/observations, ~200 columns/variables) and have run a series of Generalized Linear Mixed Models (glmm) using lme4 using some of the variables. Many of the variables used having missing data (I have accounted much of the missing data using imputation or other methods where appropriate, but still quite a lot remains), so obviously many rows were excluded from the original data frame due to listwise deletion.

I now need to do some descriptive statistical work (mostly frequencies due to many of the variables being ordinal/nominal).

Is there an easy way to subset the original data frame based on which observations were included in my given glmms?

It is easy enough to call up the data used in the model:

> glmm1 <- glmer(y~ var1 + var2 + var5 + etc + (1|var_level), data = df1) 
>   df1_glmm1_subset<-glmm1@frame

However this only returns the variables used in the model. I would like to perform descriptive summaries on variables not included in that model (for example var3 & var4) as well.

I could write a long & dirty subset that excludes NAs from the model variables, but figure there has to be a base function or package that allows me to subset df1 by glmm quickly and easily.

(apologies if this has been answered, but my search attempts just push me to how to use the subset feature within a lm call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to do this using build in functionality , but selecting rows that contain NA's in the modelvariables is quite common task. There might be even simpler solutions, but this is one:
Let's start with defining a dataframe and a formula object. Note, the first and last 10 observations contain missings in the model variables. Also i put the formula into a formula object, so we can use it both, for variable extraction, as well as for running the model itself.

```
testDf <- data.frame(y = rnorm(100), x1 = c(rnorm(90), rep(NA, 10)),
           x2 = c(rep(NA, 10), runif(90)), x3 = rnorm(100, 3), 
           var_level = rbinom(100, size = 3, prob = 0.5))

form <- y ~ x1 + x2 + (1|var_level)
```

Now note: `all.vars(form)` gives all variables contained in a the formula defined above. We use `lapply` to run `is.na` on all selected columns of `testDf`. The resulting list consists of logical vectors indicating the existence of missing values. It can be aggregated using the `Reduce` function and a logical OR. The aggregation is a logical vector pointing to all rows containing NA's in at least one of the model variables. Hence, to select the remainder it needs to be negated. This is done in the following line.

```
testDf[!Reduce("|", lapply(testDf[all.vars(form)], is.na)), ]
```

Having a look at the rownumbers we see that the first and last 10 rows have been removed.

Comment: Thanks! This worked well! For posterity I will mention: as I already had the model generated I used `glmm1@call$formula` within the lapply code instead of `form` (reduces the number of objects in my environment, and allows to quickly change the code for each model I have to perform this with.